# Django-tastypie multiple urls in prepend_urls

Tags: python, django, api, tastypie

I'm trying to add two different methods of accessing the same ResourceModel through the `prepend_urls()` functionality in Django-tastypie, but the second url never works.

Here is the code I have:

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        ...
        my_id_uri_name = 'my_id'
        name_uri_name = 'name'

    def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(
                r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<my_id>[\w\d_.-]+)/$"
                % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'),
                name="api_dispatch_detail_my_id"),
            url(
                r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<name>[\w\d_.-]+)/$"
                % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'),
                name="api_dispatch_detail_name"),
        ]
```

I cannot find any helpful resources about adding an additional URL here. Am I missing something trivial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved this, thanks to Zeograd's suggestion about regexp.

I changed the first {ID} expression to match on an integer and the second on a string, like so:

```
def prepend_urls(self):
        return [
            url(
                r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<my_id>\d+)/$"
                % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'),
                name="api_dispatch_detail_id"),
            url(
                r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<name>[\w\d_.-]+)/$"
                % self._meta.resource_name, self.wrap_view('dispatch_detail'),
                name="api_dispatch_detail_name"),
        ]
```

Comment: What if name equals to "123"?

Answer (score 0):

your 2 regexp are matching the same input url, as they're processed in order, the 2nd never matches.
You may want to use an intermediate url fragment to distinguish the 2, like

```
r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/by-name/(?P<name>[\w\d_.-]+)/$"
```

for the second

Comment: Is it possible to avoid doing this? Ideally, I want the URI schema to be like _/resource/{ID}/_ and _/resource/{NAME}/_

Comment: Unless I can make the first like r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/(?P<my_id>\d+)/$"

Comment: Then, use a single view and does the distinction between name and id via db queries inside the view code.
In any case, at url level, django is not capable of making the difference, hence your current behaviour.